# WooCommerce post description does not display in XML output

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make a dynamicly generated XML for Google Shopping from our Woocommerce shop. So long so good... ...everything is working correctly but I can not output the product description at all.

I tried:

```
get_the_content();
the_content();
$post->post_content
```

**Here's my code:**

```
<?php
require_once("../../../wp-load.php");

// Set the xml header
header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Echo out all the details
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>M13 Shop Feed</title>
<link>----</link>
<description>Google Merchant Feed</description>';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'product_cat' => 'tabak-taschen',
    'orderby' => '_sku',
);

query_posts($args);
if (have_posts()):

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();



        $brand = '----';
        $title = $product->get_title();
        $link = get_permalink();
        $description = $post->post_content;
        $sku = $product->get_sku();
        $price = $product->price;
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); //getting image source


        echo "<item> 
<title>$title</title>
<link>$link</link>
<description>$price €, $sku , $image[0] , $description</description>
<g:google_product_category>Heim &amp; Garten &gt; Rauchzubehör</g:google_product_category>
<g:id>$sku</g:id>
<g:condition>Neu OVP</g:condition>
<g:price>$price €</g:price>
<g:availability>Auf Lager</g:availability>
<g:image_link>$image</g:image_link>
<g:shipping>
    <g:country>UK</g:country>
    <g:service>Standard</g:service>
    <g:price>5.95 GBP</g:price>
</g:shipping>
<g:gtin></g:gtin>
<g:brand>----</g:brand>
<g:mpn></g:mpn>
<g:product_type>Tabaktasche</g:product_type>
</item>";

    endwhile;

endif;
?>
```

LIVE-EXAMPLE:  [XML Google Data Feed](http://staging.----.de/wp-content/themes/m13/m13geefeed.php)

I am wondering why this happens because `the_excerpt();` and other functions work totally normal except `the_content()` or `$post->post_content;`.

*For better understanding I put some of the variables into the description to proof that they are working*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- `$product` is not defined anywhere.
- personally, I prefer [`get_posts()` than `query_posts()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).
- in `<g:image_link>`, you should use `$image[0]`.
- you're not closing `<rss>` and `<channel>`.

The following works:

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( './wp-load.php' );

// Set the xml header
header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Echo out all the details
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>M13 Shop Feed</title>
<link>http://www.manufaktur13.de</link>
<description>Google Merchant Feed</description>';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
if ( $posts ):
    foreach( $posts as $post ) 
    {
        $brand = 'Manufaktur13';
        $title = $post->post_title;
        $link = get_permalink($post->ID);
        $description = $post->post_content;
        $product = get_product( $post );
        $sku = $product->get_sku();
        $price = $product->price;
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
        echo "
    <item> 
        <title>$title</title>
        <link>$link</link>
        <description>$price €, $sku , $image[0] , $description</description>
        <g:google_product_category>Heim &amp; Garten &gt; Rauchzubehör</g:google_product_category>
        <g:id>$sku</g:id>
        <g:condition>Neu OVP</g:condition>
        <g:price>$price €</g:price>
        <g:availability>Auf Lager</g:availability>
        <g:image_link>$image[0]</g:image_link>
        <g:shipping>
            <g:country>UK</g:country>
            <g:service>Standard</g:service>
            <g:price>5.95 GBP</g:price>
        </g:shipping>
        <g:gtin></g:gtin>
        <g:brand>Manufaktur13</g:brand>
        <g:mpn></g:mpn>
        <g:product_type>Tabaktasche</g:product_type>
    </item>
            ";
    }
endif;

echo '
</channel></rss>';
```